# Divide a combination of squares into triangle and calculate coordinates

Tags: algorithm, texture-mapping

The idea is expressed by my picture.

[image]

**For example:** I will divide `square` 1 into `triangle` 1 and 2. So the coordinate of triangle 1 is `(0, 1); (0, 0); (1, 0;)` and the triangle 2 is `(0, 1); (1, 0); (1, 1)`. Similarly to the rest of the squares.

Which algorithm i have to use in order to calculate the rest coordinates of all triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shift coordinates by (column, row). If you number triangles in linear manner, then for k-th triangle (with Wdt squares in row):

```
C = ((k - 1) / 2) mod Wdt   //integer modulo
R = (k - 1) / (2 * Wdt)  //integer division
if Odd(k)
    coords = (C, R + 1); (C, R); (C + 1, R)
else
    coords = (C, R + 1); (C + 1, R); (C + 1, R + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.